# What's wrong with my Django app deployed with Heroku? Server error 500

Tags: html, django, heroku, deployment, blogs

I made a blog using Django. I deployed it with Heroku, but when I load the page, it said Server Error 500. It is not loading my templates. What could went wrong? Maybe my settings.py is not sat up correctly. I'm new in Django and Heroku, so if anyone can help me, I would be thankful.

Here is my file tree:
[image: my file tree]

Here is a Heroku log:

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 8.0.2.
2023-03-25T21:45:52.759511+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 21:45:52 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-03-25T21:45:52.759842+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 21:45:52 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:32581 (2)
2023-03-25T21:45:52.759886+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 21:45:52 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-03-25T21:45:52.762814+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 21:45:52 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-03-25T21:45:52.816818+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 21:45:52 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-03-25T21:45:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-03-25T21:45:53.195760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408261+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 21:46:07 [8] [ERROR] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408275+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408276+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408276+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408276+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408277+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408278+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408278+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408279+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 28, in login_view
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408280+00:00 app[web.1]: return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form':form})
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408280+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408280+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408281+00:00 app[web.1]: content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408282+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408282+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408282+00:00 app[web.1]: template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408282+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408282+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408283+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408283+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/login.html
2023-03-25T21:46:07.408681+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.110 - - [25/Mar/2023:21:46:07 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T21:46:07.412397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=a0020b14-92f1-4d1d-bf27-e414a01b2bb1 fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=36ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746791+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 21:46:11 [7] [ERROR] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746805+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746806+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746806+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746806+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746807+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746808+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746808+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746809+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 28, in login_view
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746809+00:00 app[web.1]: return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form':form})
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746809+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746810+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746810+00:00 app[web.1]: content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746810+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746811+00:00 app[web.1]: template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746811+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746811+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
2023-03-25T21:46:11.746811+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/login.html
2023-03-25T21:46:11.747197+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.110 - - [25/Mar/2023:21:46:11 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T21:46:11.750779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=984f4c4d-6525-45de-853c-aabf7cc34408 fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879911+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 21:46:13 [8] [ERROR] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879924+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879925+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879925+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879925+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879926+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879927+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879928+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879928+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 28, in login_view
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879929+00:00 app[web.1]: return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form':form})
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879929+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879929+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879930+00:00 app[web.1]: content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879930+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879930+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879931+00:00 app[web.1]: template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879931+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879931+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879931+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
2023-03-25T21:46:13.879931+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/login.html
2023-03-25T21:46:13.880318+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.110 - - [25/Mar/2023:21:46:13 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T21:46:13.884046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=649752eb-e0f6-47a5-896b-f0730896728b fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2023-03-25T21:46:14.440713+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 21:46:14 [7] [WARNING] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Not Found: /favicon.ico
2023-03-25T21:46:14.441056+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.110 - - [25/Mar/2023:21:46:14 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://moviefanblog.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T21:46:14.444627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=57f3fa72-fbba-4697-a04f-4e4cc18e6fdc fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=https
2023-03-25T21:46:19.209697+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.110 - - [25/Mar/2023:21:46:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T21:46:19.213323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=94f2ff24-6c27-4105-a16f-6fa232f69196 fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=290 protocol=https
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798156+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 21:46:19 [7] [ERROR] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798177+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798194+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798195+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798195+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798196+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798197+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798198+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798199+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 28, in login_view
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798199+00:00 app[web.1]: return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form':form})
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798200+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798200+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798201+00:00 app[web.1]: content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798201+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798201+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798202+00:00 app[web.1]: template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798202+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798202+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798202+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798202+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/login.html
2023-03-25T21:46:19.798516+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.110 - - [25/Mar/2023:21:46:19 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T21:46:19.802147+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=f4994932-bdec-4a99-91a7-44cc6ba93b47 fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
```

Here is the collectstatic command:

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic -a moviefanblog
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 8.0.2.
Running python manage.py collectstatic on moviefanblog... starting, run.8170 (Basic)
Running python manage.py collectstatic on moviefanblog... connecting, run.8170 (Basic)Running python manage.py collectstatic on moviefanblog... up, run.8170 (Basic)

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /app/staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
yes

0 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 183 unmodified, 290 post-processed.
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
$ heroku logs -t -a moviefanblog
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 8.0.2.
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884964+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884964+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884965+00:00 app[web.1]: content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884966+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884966+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884966+00:00 app[web.1]: template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884966+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884966+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884967+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
2023-03-25T22:00:24.884967+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/login.html
2023-03-25T22:00:24.885374+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.17.208 - - [25/Mar/2023:22:00:24 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T22:00:24.887291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=08beeebb-8ee0-4987-9c47-9d9b4124ee4b fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2023-03-25T22:00:31.906322+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.17.208 - - [25/Mar/2023:22:00:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T22:00:31.908221+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=45b0333b-21de-4b00-84ba-2be98dfedf03 fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=302 bytes=290 protocol=https
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191150+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 22:00:34 [8] [ERROR] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191171+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191182+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191182+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191182+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191184+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191185+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191185+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191186+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 28, in login_view
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191186+00:00 app[web.1]: return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form':form})
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191186+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191186+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191187+00:00 app[web.1]: content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191187+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191187+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191187+00:00 app[web.1]: template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191188+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191188+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191188+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191188+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/login.html
2023-03-25T22:00:34.191631+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.17.208 - - [25/Mar/2023:22:00:34 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T22:00:34.193525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=2eccb3c4-aea7-46e0-ad8c-0c165861fd2a fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2023-03-25T22:00:52.041638+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic` by user bakonyirobi@freemail.hu
2023-03-25T22:00:55.290133+00:00 heroku[run.6347]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-25T22:00:55.409287+00:00 heroku[run.6347]: Awaiting client
2023-03-25T22:00:55.425132+00:00 heroku[run.6347]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic`
2023-03-25T22:01:07.318469+00:00 heroku[run.6347]: Process exited with status 0
2023-03-25T22:01:07.359538+00:00 heroku[run.6347]: State changed from up to complete
2023-03-25T22:04:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bakonyirobi@freemail.hu
2023-03-25T22:05:06.361778+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user bakonyirobi@freemail.hu
2023-03-25T22:05:06.361778+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c05a167d by user bakonyirobi@freemail.hu
2023-03-25T22:05:07.454916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2023-03-25T22:05:07.472549+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2023-03-25T22:05:08.361879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2023-03-25T22:05:08.406102+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:08 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-03-25T22:05:08.406147+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:08 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2023-03-25T22:05:08.406286+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:08 +0000] [2] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-03-25T22:05:08.410439+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:08 +0000] [2] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8 was terminated due to signal 15
2023-03-25T22:05:08.506927+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:08 +0000] [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2023-03-25T22:05:08.653294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2023-03-25T22:05:10.692784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn blog.wsgi`
2023-03-25T22:05:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-03-25T22:05:14.099996+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:14 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-03-25T22:05:14.100281+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:14 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3600 (2)
2023-03-25T22:05:14.100317+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:14 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-03-25T22:05:14.103134+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:14 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-03-25T22:05:14.165659+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 22:05:14 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-03-25T22:05:15.452413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-25T22:05:44.243105+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic` by user bakonyirobi@freemail.hu
2023-03-25T22:05:47.189462+00:00 heroku[run.3465]: Awaiting client
2023-03-25T22:05:47.212056+00:00 heroku[run.3465]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-25T22:05:48.768030+00:00 heroku[run.3465]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic`
2023-03-25T22:05:58.067338+00:00 heroku[run.3465]: Process exited with status 0
2023-03-25T22:05:58.068679+00:00 heroku[run.3465]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2023-03-25T22:05:58.118522+00:00 heroku[run.3465]: State changed from up to complete
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229182+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 22:06:21 [8] [ERROR] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229196+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229197+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229198+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229198+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229199+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229200+00:00 app[web.1]: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229200+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229201+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/accounts/views.py", line 28, in login_view
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229208+00:00 app[web.1]: return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form':form})
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229208+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229209+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229210+00:00 app[web.1]: content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229210+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229210+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229211+00:00 app[web.1]: template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229211+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229212+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229212+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229212+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/login.html
2023-03-25T22:06:21.229983+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.69 - - [25/Mar/2023:22:06:21 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T22:06:21.230211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=c9e6dc7c-ba6f-4b11-80a6-b03a0ca6df3e fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=51ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2023-03-25T22:06:21.382401+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-03-25 22:06:21 [8] [WARNING] pathname=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/log.py lineno=224 funcname=log_response Not Found: /favicon.ico
2023-03-25T22:06:21.382763+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.61.69 - - [25/Mar/2023:22:06:21 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://moviefanblog.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-03-25T22:06:21.383041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=moviefanblog.herokuapp.com request_id=241b16cd-c3db-4ed7-b95a-ef05156a4371 fwd="89.133.248.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=https
2023-03-25T22:14:27.945785+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user bakonyirobi@freemail.hu
2023-03-25T22:14:30.965601+00:00 heroku[run.2927]: Awaiting client
2023-03-25T22:14:30.980683+00:00 heroku[run.2927]: Starting process with command `bash`
2023-03-25T22:14:31.049505+00:00 heroku[run.2927]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-25T22:15:56.913667+00:00 heroku[run.2927]: Process exited with status 0
2023-03-25T22:15:56.953154+00:00 heroku[run.2927]: State changed from up to complete
----------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------
$ heroku run bash
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 8.0.2.
Running bash on moviefanblog... starting, run.2927 (Basic)
Running bash on moviefanblog... connecting, run.2927 (Basic)Running bash on moviefanblog... up, run.2927 (Basic)
~ $ python manage.py collectstatic
pythpython manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /app/staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
yes

0 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 183 unmodified, 306 post-processed.
```

It said */app/staticfiles* but I don't have *staticfiles* folder, I have *statics* folder. Is it a cause of Heroku does not find my templates? They are in the retated app's Templates folder.
Additional Information: Users can upload pictures for the articles, otherwise, the default-movie will be uploaded.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Originally it was pasted as codeblocks, but it exceeded the character limits

Comment: @Chris What should I do? Just delete the Heroku logs, because searching in settings.py more important?

Comment: The logs are the _most_ important thing. They tell you where to look. In this case, you're getting a `TemplateNotFoundException`. Are you trying to use a custom `accounts/login.html` template? Why are you showing anything related to static files? Why are you trying to show your entire `settings.py`?

Comment: Because I thought the problem is with static path in settins.py. Locally it worked perfectly. But after deploy I get a server error 500 and my login page not showing.(I need to log in first after that I can go to the articles page). And my htmls not loaded

Comment: @Chris Have you got any idea how can I solve this kind of problem?

Comment: @Chris The Error is TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
accounts/login.html